# Service Console If Case View has override to VF page Refresh this Tab no longer works

Tags: service-cloud-console

I have an Override for Case View to go to a basic Visualforce page as shown:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
    <apex:detail subject="{!Case.Id}" relatedList="true" inlineEdit="true" showChatter="true"/>        
</apex:page>
```

If I click on the drop down arrow at the far right of the Console and click the "Refresh This Tab" icon for any of the Case tabs the Tab does not refresh.  Clicking "Refresh all primary tabs" also does not refresh the tab.  Clicking "Close all primary tabs" does close the tab.

[image]

Similarly if the case is edited by another user I am also NOT seeing the alert that normally would show up at the top of the page saying this record was changed by someone else ...click refresh.  I have the Console setting to put a flag on the page which is not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well unless someone has different information it looks like this is a documented limitation of the Console.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=console2_limitations.htm&language=en_US

**Behavior and Access Limitations**

*Visualforce pages don’t refresh when you click the down arrow and select Refresh all primary tabs or Refresh all subtabs.*

Comment: This is correct.